# How can I create a pixmap based on a .png file?

Tags: linux, icons, png, archlinux, pixmap

I have some ***.png* icons** I want to use for window buttons in a custom theme I want to create For **fluxbox**. My operating system is **Arch Linux**. But, fluxbox works **with *pixmaps*.**

**Question:** Is it possible to create *pixmaps* based on *.png* format files?

Comment: A 'pixmap' seems a high level construction but is actually: "the name of a .xpm file stored in pixmaps". So all you have to do is convert the PNG to an XPM.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the program *convert* from ImageMagick:

```
xiawi@here:~/Images$ convert lena.png lena.xpm
xiawi@here:~/Images$ file lena.xpm 
lena.xpm: X pixmap image, ASCII text, with very long lines
```